# ElasticSearch for terms with spaces

Tags: elasticsearch

We are running ElasticSearch and are having some issues when searching for terms that contain a space. A concrete example: there is an a person named JM Bruno, but when searching for this no results are returned. I vaguely remember searching for this exact term did return the result, but I can't reproduce that right now.

I tried adding a space as well as "\ " to my tokenizer pattern, without much luck. The ES settings are the following (using the Tire gem in a Ruby on Rails application)

```
module Search
def self.included base
base.send :include, Tire::Model::Search
base.send :include, Tire::Model::Callbacks

base.class_eval do
  settings  analysis: {
              filter: {
                ngram: {
                  type: 'nGram',
                  max_gram: 12,
                  min_gram: 3
                },
                url_stop: {
                  type: "stop",
                  stopwords: %w[http https]
                }
              },
              tokenizer: {
                url_email_tokenizer: {
                  pattern: '[^\w\-\.@]+',
                  type: 'pattern'
                }
              },
              analyzer: {
                url_analyzer: {
                  tokenizer: "url_email_tokenizer",
                  filter: %w[url_stop ngram],
                  type: "custom"
                },
                name_analyzer: {
                  tokenizer: 'url_email_tokenizer',
                  filter: 'ngram',
                  type: 'custom'
                }
              }
            }


    end
  end
end
```

We use these tokenizers to search for domain names and email addresses as well.

Answer (score 4):

Try to run [_analyze API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-analyze.html) with the analyzer you applied to your field.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_analyze?analyzer=name_analyzer' -d 'JM Bruno'
```

You will see how Elasticsearch breaks your field content into tokens and why you can not search for it using a TermQuery. A TermQuery is not analyzed so it compares your query exactly as is with the inverted index.

Comment: it returns a 400 code with the error 'failed to find analyzer'. Isn't ES aware of what I use for settings in the Tire gem when it comes to analyzers?

Comment: Try MyModel.index.analyze "My text", analyzer: "name_analyzer"

Comment: figured out I needed to add the index, but the response doesn't mean much to me. Sure, it finds a bunch of tokens as I'd expect them to be tokenized by the ngram, but that doesn't explain why it's not included in the search (at least, it's not clear to me)

Comment: Try also using the http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/uaxurlemail-tokenizer.html tokenizer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of term query this can be search by using

In Java by using advance rest client

```
query.must((QueryBuilders.matchQuery("name", searchMap.get("JM Bruno")).minimumShouldMatch("100%")));
```

in elastic search directly

GET /_search

```
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "name" : {
                "query" : "JM Bruno",
                "cutoff_frequency" : 0.001
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using Django and there I encountered this error by setting the analyzer to "keyword". That's it. By default it uses the "standard" analyzer.

It will not make tokens on the basis of whitespace. It will consider your whole text as a single token. The default limit is up to 256 characters.

here is my code. I used elasticsearch_dsl. This is my document.py file

```
from django_elasticsearch_dsl import Document, fields
from elasticsearch_dsl import analyzer
from .models import Job

html_strip = analyzer(
    'html_strip',
    tokenizer= 'keyword',
    filter=['lowercase'],
)

@registry.register_document
class MyDocument(Document):
    title = fields.TextField(
        analyzer=html_strip,
        fields={'raw': fields.KeywordField()}
    )

class Index:
    name = 'jobs'  # Name of Elasticsearch index
    settings = {
        'number_of_shards': 1,
        'number_of_replicas': 0
    }

class Django:
    model = Job
    fields = [
        'salary_min',
        'salary_high'
    ]
```

This is my view.py file. Here I am querying the search object. Here I am using a function where the keyword is passed which needs to be searched.

```
def search_job_titles_for_autocomplete(keyword):
    autocomplete = list()
    search = f"*{keyword}*"

    queryset = JobDocument.search().query('wildcard', title=search)
    
    for job in queryset:
        job_to_dict = job.to_dict()
        autocomplete.append(job_to_dict["title"])

return autocomplete
```

It returns the list of titles and my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a [multi-field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html)

Also take a look at this very cool [tutorial](http://joelabrahamsson.com/elasticsearch-101/)

Answer (score -1):

I've encountered the same issue and the only thing I came up to was just replacing space character with "?" wildcard. It looked like default tokenizer as well as one I was specifically requesting in query string search were ignored.